# Calling "requires 'rack'" multiple times in nested file includes

Tags: ruby

if i have a.rb:

```
require 'rack'
require 'b'
```

and my b.rb is:

```
//do something with rack
```

Does b.rb need to also say:

```
require 'rack'
```

if b.rb will only ever be 'require'd by a.rb?

I'm seeing a lot of code where a.rb requires 'rack' and includes b.rb which also requires 'rack'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that rack will always have been required before b is required, then there is no need to `require 'rack'` inside b.rb.  This can cause problems if you ever reorganize your code to require things in a different order, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
require 'rack' if defined?(Rack).nil?
```

This just tests to see if the constant for Rack, which is a module, is defined and requires it if the constant is nil.